# How do you prevent a circular import exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, import, module

I have been trying to link a main module with another module, both need each other to perform a specific task, so I imported them to each other, but I get an error about circular importation. I've been trying to avoid this but it keeps raising the error, please how do I correct this??

Comment: Create a 3rd module for the task that imports both?

Comment: Reorganize your program so you don't need the circular import. Your current module structure isn't an absolute requirement.

Comment: Read a guid how to create an modul its sounds like that u have an issue with the structure of your Modul. It will Help u

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a **3rd module**, from which you can then import the functions, classes and variables to the 2 other scripts. Normally issues like these are signs of poor code structuring. 2 separate scripts should **never** both depend on one another at the same time. Avoid such design blunders in the future.

Comment: Yes, those issues are often signs of poor design, but I disagree with the strict **never**. There are situations, where the relationship of classes forms a cycle, because it reflects the reality.

Comment: @VPfB then those classes should be located to the same module, as the functionality should be kept inside the very module itself and not be distributed chaotically. Altough you may be right for some specific scenarios, when it might be the best solution to create such a  structure. There's **always** exceptions in software development.

Comment: @Bialomazur But when you reach say 1000+ lines of code, you want to split such module for the sake of readability and maintainability.

Comment: @VPfB that is true, but in that occasion one can simply distribute the classes by taking advantage of the **__init__.py** module initialization. One of its main causes is indeed to  prevent having to face such errors and still be able to structure code in a senseful manner.